# Query Elasticsearch via Axios

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, axios

I have an Elasticsearch instance that I can successfully query from Postman. I'm now trying to execute that same query from JavaScript via [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). However, when I send my Axios request, I receive a 400 error. Currently, my request looks like this:

```
try {
  let authorizationToken = getAuthToken();
  let parameters = {
    headers: {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + authorizationToken
    },
    body: {
      "size": 100,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            { "range": { 
              "created_at": {"gte":"now-10m"}
            } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  };

  let url = 'https://my-cluster-address/my-index/_search?scroll=10m';
  let res = await axios.post(url, parameters);

  console.log('all good');
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex);
}
```

What is wrong with my query? Why am I getting a 400 error?

Comment: What does the console.log statement inside the catch block print?

Comment: In the catch block, I see `Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?